# <input> Rejeitar determinado caractere

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5

Por exemplo como ficaria minha *tag/script* para rejeitar a virgula de um `<input>` em tempo real? Não quero permitir que este caractere seja colocado no `input` e depois de a invalidação quero que assim que a pessoa tecle o caractere ele não "*imprima*" no `input`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

É só pegar o código da tecla com `onkeydown` e retornar `false` caso seja igual a 188 (vígula do teclado alfanumérico) ou 110 (vírgula do teclado numérico):

```js
document.getElementById("campo").onkeydown = function(e){
   var tecla = e.keyCode || e.which;
   if(tecla == 188 || tecla == 110) return false;
}
```

```html
<input id="campo" autofocus>
```